# Is a connection class in classic ASP overkill?

Tags: class, asp-classic

I am stuck with some classic asp files at the moment, but I'd like to consolidate some of the code.  I found this and wanted to get an opinion.  Is this overkill?  Would a robust connection class be useful?  I was going to try to create as best I could a separation of concerns, and I'm working on the model.  Since I cannot inherit by extends (that I can find), I thought I'd just include this class in each model file:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?491770-Build-a-Database-Connections-Class-in-Classic-ASP

```
Class clsDatabaseConnections
    Private strConnection   ''# Connection string (change depending on what system we are using)
    Private objConn         ''# Connection object
    Private objComm         ''# Command Object
    Private objRS           ''# Recordset object

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        ''# What happens when the class is opened
        strConnection = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; ..........."

        Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        objConn.ConnectionString = strConnection        
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        ''# What happens when the class is closed

        ''# Close connections
        If objConn.State <> 0 Then
            objConn.Close   
        End If
        Set objConn = Nothing
    End Sub         

    Public Sub SQLExecuteFromSQLString(ByRef strSQL)
        ''# Execute code and return nothing
        If objConn.State <> 0 Then
            objConn.Close
        End If  

        objConn.Execute strSQL      
    End Sub

    ''# This replicates the .NET ExecuteScalar
    Public Function ExecuteScalarFromSQLString(ByRef sSQL)
        ''# This is used when passing back single results. Replicating a .NET piece of functionality
        Dim objScalar
        Set objScalar = GetRecordSet(sSQL)

        If Not objScalar.EOF Then
            ExecuteScalar = objScalar(0)
        Else
            ''# Nothing returned
            ExecuteScalar = -1
        End If

        CloseRecordSet()
    End Function ''#ExecuteScalar

    Public Function GetRecordSetFromSQLString(ByRef strRS)
        If objConn.State <> 1 Then
            objConn.Open
        End If

        Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        objRS.Open strRS, objConn

        Set GetRecordSet = objRS
    End Function

    ''# Using SP code within class
    ''##########################################################################
    Public Sub CallSPNeedParams(ByRef strStoredProc)
        If objConn.State <> 1 Then
            objConn.Open
        End If

        If Not IsObject(objComm) Then
            Set objComm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") ''# This will be used for Stored Procedures
        End If

        With objComm
            .ActiveConnection = objConn
            .CommandText = strStoredProc
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        End With

        If Not IsObject(objRS) Then
            Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        End If

        Set objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn ''# Set connection
        Set objRS.Source = objComm  ''# Set source to use command object            
    End Sub

    Public Sub ApendParamsToRecordSet(ByRef Name, ByRef TypeParam, ByRef Direction, ByRef Size, ByRef Value)
        ''#Type adDate adDBDate, adVarChar, adChar, adBoolean
        If IsObject(objComm) Then
            objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter(Name, TypeParam, Direction, Size, Value)          
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetRecordSetSPParams(ByRef strStoredProc)
        If strStoredProc = objComm.CommandText Then
            ''# This is being called for the right SP
            objRS.Open
            Set GetRecordSetSPParams = objRS

            ''# Need to clear out params from Command object
            Do While (objComm.Parameters.Count > 0)
                objComm.Parameters.Delete 0
            Loop

        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub CloseCommObject()
        If IsObject(objComm) Then
            Set objComm = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
    ''##########################################################################

    Public Function ExecuteScalarSetSPParams(ByRef strStoredProc)
        ''# This is used when passing back single results. Replicating a .NET piece of functionality
        If strStoredProc = objComm.CommandText Then     
            objRS.Open
            If Not objRS.EOF Then
                ExecuteScalar = objRS(0)
            Else
                ''# Nothing returned
                ExecuteScalar = -1
            End If

            CloseRecordSet()
        End If
    End Function ''#ExecuteScalar               

    Public Sub ExecuteSPButNoRecordsReturned(ByRef strStoredProc)
        If strStoredProc = objComm.CommandText Then
            objComm.Execute
        End If
    End Sub ''#ExecuteSPButNoRecordsReturned()

    Public Sub CloseRecordSet() 
        If objRS.State <> 0 Then
            objRS.Close 
        End If

        Set objRS = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Property Get ObjectConn()
        ObjectConn = objConn
    End Property    

    Public Property Let SwitchConnection(ByRef strConn)
        ''# Will allow user to change the connection from the default set up    
        strConnection = strConn
        Call SwitchConnection(strConnection)
    End Property

    Private Sub SwitchConnection(ByRef strConn)
        ''# Will allow user to change the connection from the default set up    
        strConnection = strConn
        If objConn.State <> adStateClosed Then
            objConn.ConnectionString = strConnection
        End If
    End Sub

End Class ''#clsDatabaseConnections
```

Comment: http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/database/datafunctions.asp?ID=AW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer?  It depends.

If you have just a few files that would include and use such a class, I would say it's not likely worth the effort to create such a class and refactor the including files.

If you have a large library or set of libraries that you believe have a significant time to obsolescence/replacement, go for it.

In the past I have created similar (though not nearly so robust) classes for large data-dependent ASP libraries, placing them in the folder hierarchy so that they would be usable by numerous apps.

The big benefit I see from doing this, aside from simplicity, is the ability to ensure your connection(s) and other resources are properly closed/managed...you don't want to anger the DBAs ;?)